# Looking to integrate free templates from 'https://startbootstrap.com/' into my react app

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap, reactstrap

I want to download one of the free bootstrap [templates](https://startbootstrap.com/) and add said template to my react app. I tried reading some of the documents but I can't find any documentation on integrating these free templates with react.

I did an `npm install` for the template I liked but I'm not sure what to do next. I just have the template in my `node_modules` directory.

I took what was in the body of the html file in the template and threw it in the return for my `app.js`. Added the css and vendor folder. Then I tried to import the templates css file to my `app.js` as well as change what was needed in my `index.html` file. Some of it worked. Other parts didn't.

Just looking to properly integrate these nice looking templates into my react projects.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is these [templates](https://startbootstrap.com/templates/) are built with Bootstrap in mind **not** React. These templates were created using regular HTML, CSS, JS, jQuery, etc.. and won't work out of the box for a React application. So in order to get one of these templates to work, within the context of React, one will have make manual changes to numerous parts of said template.

For example, in addition to grabbing the pieces of the template desired for your React application one will have to change numerous attributes listed within the HTML pages provided by the template. This is because in **React you can't use keywords reserved for JavaScript in JSX**.

*So what does this mean?*

You'll have to change the `class` attributes in the HTML to `className` for your CSS style rules to take effect from the template. `onchange` becomes `onChange`, `onsubmit` becomes `onSubmit`, etc...

The standard is to **camelCase reserved JavaScript keywords** in JSX.

You can definitely get this template to work in React it will just involve some *manual tweaking on your end*. However, if you want a template to work out of the box for React I would look into a free template built with React in mind.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: ahh it seems I overlooked that part. Let me try it out. Thannkks!

Comment: np glad it helped, please consider accepting my answer if you found it useful

Comment: I changed the class to className and other attributes. But still no good. I think the import and <link> <script> may be off. Or there may be other issues.

Comment: Did you by any chance give it a shot to try and merge it?

Comment: There will be numerous issues. I only gave an example issue for the styling. For example, you will need the the <script> tags to be within you index.html page within your public folder. Ideally, you should just install the necessary libs through npm/yarn. It will involve a good amount of tinkering and understanding of the differences between react development and regular web development. If you're deadset on using that template I might consider using the template as is and adding react to that template: https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html.

Comment: Awesome! This doc looks really useful. I'm reading into now. Will try to do this when I understand it a bit more. seems like a better way of going about using these themes with react. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: np, best of luck!